# Return all elements followed by an equal element using list comprehensions

Tags: list, erlang

So I'm new to Erlang and still on the learning curve, one question asked was to return all elements in a list followed by an equal element, to which I could to.
For example...

```
in_pair_lc([a,a,a,2,b,a,r,r,2,2,b,a]) -> [a,a,r,2]
```

I was then asked to do the same using a list comprehension, and I hit my mental block.
My unsuccessful attempt was this:

```
in_pair_lc([]) -> [];
in_pair_lc([H|T]) ->
   [X || X ,_ [H|T], X=lists:nth(X+1, [H|T]).
```

Although with no look ahead in list comp it doesn't work.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this with a list comprehension is to create two lists from the input list:

- one containing all elements except the very first element
- one containing all elements except the very last element

By zipping these two lists together, we get a list of tuples where each tuple consists of adjacent elements from the input list. We can then use a list comprehension to take only those tuples whose elements match:

```
in_pair_lc([_|T]=L) ->
    [_|T2] = lists:reverse(L),
    [H || {H,H} <- lists:zip(lists:reverse(T2),T)].
```

EDIT: based on the discussion in the comments, with Erlang/OTP version 17.0 or newer, the two list reversals can be replaced with `lists:droplast/1`:

```
in_pair_lc([_|T]=L) ->
    [H || {H,H} <- lists:zip(lists:droplast(L), T)].
```

The first example will work on both older and newer versions of Erlang/OTP.

Comment: I think I'm understanding this correctly… Why do you reverse the list twice? Couldn't you just drop the tail? It would reduce time by a factor of 2.

Comment: The [`lists:droplast/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#droplast-1) function was added only in Erlang/OTP 17.0, so older versions don't have it. The code in the answer works on new and old versions of Erlang/OTP. If you have 17.0 or newer, you could replace the entire function body in the answer with `[H||{H,H} <- lists:zip(lists:droplast(L), T)]`.

Comment: Ah, wonderful, thank you for enlightening me. I just got into Erlang and I have the latest version. +1 for portability.

Comment: Dropping the last element of a list is still inefficient. Since lists are single-linked and immutable, dropping the last requires traversing and copying it. Here is the source-code of `lists:droplast/1` in the standard library (with an interesting comment): https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L213

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the problem is really about list comprehensions. The core of the problem is zipping lists and then using a trivial "filter" expression in the list comprehension.

If you want to stick to basic, long existing, erlang list functions (`sublist`, `nthtail`) you could go with the following:

```
X = [a,a,a,2,b,a,r,r,2,2,b,a].
[A || {A,A} <- lists:zip(lists:sublist(X, length(X)-1), lists:nthtail(1, X))].
```